USD beam to support ultimate moment of 650kN-m, limited to an effective depth of 600mm and 300mm width. Effective depth for compression steel is 60mm
I don't understand how exactly can a beam as described can support a 650kN-m ultimate moment. The only allowed bars are 28mm∅ bars. Consider 40mm side covering and bar spacing to be greater or equal to 28mm, the only acceptable choice is 4-28mm∅ bars. Is there a way to make it doubly reinforced or is the question my professor gave me wrong? fc'=30MPa and fy=410MPa
On another consideration, the load was not mentioned as ultimate moment. If I treat it as a nominal moment, it still isn't manageable. Is there something I'm missing?

What are the units KN-m?

Are you asking what kN-m is? If you are, that's kilonewton meter. @SolarMike

So if thew N is defined as kgm/s^2, then you have (kgm/s^2)-m perhaps? or did you mean kn/m?

It's a moment. It's Force multiplied to the Moment arm.

What is a USD beam?

I usually do the dirty trick of dividing the moment by 0.9 effective depth to get a rough estimate of compression or tension force.
$$\frac{650kNm}{0.54m}=1,203,700N \approx120,000kg $$
$$\frac{120,000}{4500kg/cm^2}=26cm^2 \ steel\ area$$
$$26/(1.4^2 *\pi)=4.33\ say \ 5 \ 28mm \ bars$$
This is the estimated unfactored loads, then I would consider load combinations and refine this. But assuming J as 0.90 of effective depth is a good estimate!
